# Why can't I pipe into gpg --recv-keys?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stdin, gnupg

I have been stumped here for a couple weeks on and off.  I have a file that contains a key, I can get that key and print (to stdout) via something like `grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p"` but then anything  I do to try and pipe the output of that into `gpg --recv-keys` just doesn't work. There's no error it just seems like the pipe doesn't work or the command is not run at all.

Originally I started with this

```
grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p" | gpg --recv-keys
```

that didn't work so I kept looking around until I got to this:

```
gpg --recv-keys <(grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p")
```

which gave me the response:`gpg: "/dev/fd/63" not a key ID: skipping`
so I played around with this variation to get things like

```
gpg --recv-keys <(grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p" | cat)
```

or

```
gpg --recv-keys < <(grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p")
```

or

```
gpg --recv-keys <<< grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p"
```

but nothing seems to work.  It's almost as if the command can recognize that something is being pipd in and avoids it be cause if i take the output of `grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p")` and paste it to the end of `gpg --recv-keys` it works fine.  So lets say  the first command produces something like `ABCDEFG12345` if I do `gpg --recv-keys ABCDEFG12345` it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that really a key, or the ID OF a key? I suspect the latter. For an actual key just pipe into `gpg --import`; `--recv-keys` is used with ID(s) _as argument(s) not input_ (see my comment on the A) to fetch that key or those keys from a server.

Comment: So honestly I'm not sure but if I manually copy the output of `grep validpgpkeys PKGBUILD | sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p"`  and then paste it after `gpg --recv-keys` it works. So let's say the first command produces something like `ABCDEFG12345 ` if I do `gpg --recv-keys ABCDEFG12345` it works fine.

Comment: Not taking a pipe is intentional behavior. Why, I'm not really sure, but it's possible that someone on the GPG team decided there was a security risk with accepting keyids from a pipe. It might be worth [trying a compound command](https://superuser.com/questions/851434/is-there-a-way-to-pass-arguments-via-pipe-on-bash) to make things work for your use-case

Comment: If you paste a value like ABCDEF123 _after_ `gpg --recv-keys` that makes it _an argument NOT input_ -- exactly as I said. A pipe does NOT do that; a pipe provides input and not an argument, and that's wrong for `--recv-keys`. Since the A with my comment has been deleted: you can get the effect of pasting by doing `gpg --recv-keys $( grep_and_sed )` or have `xargs` do it for you with `grep_and_sed | xargs gpg --recv-keys`.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying, for some reason didn't click last time.  Thank you!